# When should I use Shared Locking (Read Locking)

Tags: multithreading, thread-safety, locking, mutex

Can someone explain when shared locks should be used. If I understand correctly, shared locks are used when reading and exclusive locks are used while writing.

But why can't I just wait while a mutex is locked when doing a read.

Comment: The pattern you describe is the most *common* use for shared and exclusive locks, but not the *only* sensible strategy. Another I've seen several times when there is some sort of partitioning of data (and that entire data set is protected by a single lock) with each partition having an owner, is that the owner can both read and write data in its own partition with a shared lock, but must acquire an exclusive lock for accessing other partitions for any access, read or write. This works well when a very high percentage of access is within the owner's partition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is for improving performance. Multiple concurrent reads then won't have to happen sequentially, which may be a great bonus if the structure is read frequently. (But still the data read will be consistent and up to date.)

Answer (score 1):

> But why can't I just wait while a mutex is locked when doing a read.

Usually for speed. Shared locks allow multiple readers, as the content is not changing. Exclusive lock allows only a single (typically) write operation as you want all the writes to be atomic.

More technical definitions from [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cicsts/v3r2/topic/com.ibm.cics.ts.applicationprogramming.doc/topics/dfhp39o.html).

> **Exclusive locks** protect updates to file resources, both recoverable
>   and non-recoverable. They can be owned by only one transaction at a
>   time. Any transaction that requires an exclusive lock must wait if
>   another task currently owns an exclusive lock or a shared lock against
>   the requested resource. Shared locks
>
> **Shared locks** support read integrity. They ensure that a record is not
>   in the process of being updated during a read-only request. Shared
>   locks can also be used to prevent updates of a record between the time
>   that a record is read and the next syncpoint.

Answer (score 1):

A shared locks (also known as read locks) prohibits any other process from requesting a write lock on the specified part of the file. However, other processes can request read locks and keep reading from the resource.

An exclusive lock (also known as write lock) gives a process an exclusive access for writing to the specified part of the file and will prevent any other process to acquire any kind of locking to the resource until the exclusive lock is released.

So a read lock says "you can read now but if you want to write you'll have to wait" whereas a write lock says "you'll have to wait".

For an official description, check out the [official locks documentation of GNU C library](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/File-Locks.html).

In addition, in many cases, the context of shared/exclusive locking is pessimistic/optimistic locking which is a methodology used to handle multi-users read/write to the same resource. Here is an [explanation of the methodology](http://www.dbasupport.com/forums/showthread.php?7282-What-is-Optimistic-Locking-vs-Pessimistic-Locking&s=c915c57b82a802409e38038123eac376&p=29149#post29149).

Answer (score 0):

> But why can't I just wait while a mutex is locked when doing a read.

Because that would be inefficient in certain scenarios, specifically those where a lot of threads are reading a data structure often, but very few are writing and not very often. Since multiple concurrent reads are thread-safe if no one is writing, it would be a waste to have mutual exclusion for the readers.

Imagine a server and multiple clients doing various transactions on some shared data. If most of these clients are simply asking for information, but not changing anything, the server would have horrible performance if it only allowed one client to read at a time.